# how to send radio button data to database from button click popover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

I am new in php html. In my app I have a button and href. I want to make button click popover and 3 radio button inside that. I want to update data in database using radio switch without any submit button. But I am unable to open popover.href is using for a modal open and view data.

I want when that button clicked popover come and that radio button data goes to mysql database but I am unable to do that. I want both modal and popover. How I can do that?

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var modal = $(this);
  var dataString = 'bclassid=' + recipient;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "editdata.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      modal.find('.dash').html(data);
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="dataTable_wrapper">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
      <tr style="background-color: #d7ccc8;">

        <th>CLASS</th>

        <th>OPTION</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,"select bclassid,bclassname,status from bclassinfo");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "<tr class='odd gradeX'>";
          echo "<td align=center><a href='#myModal' data-whatever=" . $row[0] ."  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal '>" .  $row[1] . "</a></td>";
          echo "<td><a class='btn btn-small btn-primary'">Edit</a></td>";//button to open popover with three radio button
          echo "</tr>";
            }
          ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="../../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: i want to made a popover with some radio button..I tried some code.With out modal its work but modal and popover not working.

Comment: Might help: http://jsfiddle.net/apougher/rjRwV/

Comment: i want a href also with this button.I want both run in same page

Comment: Just attach your a tag to popover using the a tag's id attribute.

Comment: Same way you did with the button.

Comment: no...It is not working in my code..try tried that.

Comment: see my href code..I get data using id from href to my modal.I want a button right of href to open another popover with 3 radio switch and that id.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9g48qpo7/